# php generator/visual programming for asynchronous multiplayer backend?

Tags: php, mysql, generator, backend, multiplayer

I've gotten pretty good at making single player games with a game making program. It can also make HTTP requests (get and post, listen for response). As someone who does not know any programming languages I've been very glad to see how well I can make a single player game. Now I have to learn to make the backend.

My understanding is that PHP/MySQL is the way I should probably go for this asynchronous multiplayer game (IOS). I've been getting the hang of some ways to setup and edit the MySQL portion, things like MySQL workbench etc.

When it comes to generating PHP pages that can allow this, I've mostly used "PHPmySQL" and "ScriptArtist3". They both would do the trick if I were trying to set up a browser interface for people to interact with a database, but from what I've seen, I don't think they can give me what I need:

The ability to make pages that will interact with the simple HTTP Get and Post requests coming from my game, work with the database and handle the backend logic. Is there a code generating software that I can use that will do that?

Also, I've been getting a fairly good idea of how MySQL works, and how PHP files can be set up to add, edit, delete, etc. But when it comes to actually handling more complicated logic I'm not sure the smartest way to do that, and could use some insight there as well.

I'm also open to different kind of solutions for the backend (keeping in mind that for my client I am limited to the HTTP requests).

Any insight would be very much appreciated!

Comment: shouldn't this be done in Objective-C ?

Comment: Yeah.... if its IOS, you should know ObjC, but I think I would use Node.js for the backend, as its non blocking, although PHP can do websockets

Comment: Dagon: The actual game client will be generated in Objective-C. As far as the server side of things I've generally been told that PHP/MySQL is the way to go.

KyleK: I'm open to looking into Node.js, if there are code generating programs for non coders I can use to set things up that way.